# Ajax post multiple data to flask

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax, flask

The way I send one data to flask

.js

```
function func(s) {

  let toPost = {name: f.name, sf: split.f};
  let jsonStr = JSON.stringify(toPost);
  $.ajax({
      url: "temp",
      type: "POST",
      data: JSON.stringify(data),
      processData: false,
      contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
      success: function(){
        console.log("success")
      }    
    });
}
```

.py

```
@app.route('/temp', methods = ['POST'])
def temp() :

    jsonStr = request.get_json()
    file_object = open('temp.txt', 'a')
    file_object.write(jsonStr)
    file_object.write("\n")
    file_object.close()

    return render_template('temp.txt')
```

But I would like to send multiple data, so the ajax look like this:

```
data: {str: JSON.stringify(data), method: "add"}
```

Everything else remains the same.

In the .py file how could I get both `str` and `method` as well?

**errors**

console

```
jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4          POST FILENAME 400 (BAD REQUEST)
```

com

```
127.0.0.1 - - [] "POST /FILENAME HTTP/1.1" 400 -
```

full error

[image]
[image]

Comment: what do u mean by multiple data , you can modify the payload as u want

Comment: @AtifShafi if I use data: {str: JSON.stringify(data), method: "add"} at .js file, and jsonStr = request.get_json() in the .py file I am getting an error

Comment: mention the err in question

Comment: @AtifShafi I have just added the error codes

Comment: it seems that the url u have mentioned is incorrect , if u are on the same host machine try putting `url: "/temp",`

Comment: `$.ajax({
            url:'/temp',
            type: "POST",
            data: data,
            dataType:'json'
            success: function(){
                console.log("success")
              }    
            });`

Comment: dataType:'json' is not vaid, plus this is still give me the same error

Comment: can u post the complete error log, also expected response and your request json sent

Comment: @AtifShafi I have uploaded ptrSc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code leaves a lot of room for speculation.
The error message you get results from the fact that you want to send data as JSON but do not format it completely compliantly.

Normally, submitted objects are automatically sent as form data and formatted accordingly beforehand. You suppress this behavior by setting the `processData` parameter to `false`. However, this also means that the formatting to JSON must also be done by you. Otherwise a string representation of the transferred object would be sent, which the server cannot interpret.

As the following example shows, you should convert all data to JSON using `JSON.stringify(...)` before sending it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Index</title>
    <style media="screen">
      output {
        white-space: pre;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form name="my-form">
      <input type="text" name="name" />
      <input type="text" name="sf" />
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
    <output name="result"></output>

    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(() => {
        $('form[name="my-form"]').submit(function(evt) {
          evt.preventDefault();
          const form = $(this);

          const formData = {};
          $.each(form.serializeArray(), (_, row) => {
            formData[row.name] = row.value;
          });
          // => { name: <anything>, sf: <something> }
          console.log(formData);

          const method = 'add';
          const data = { data: formData, method: method };
          // => { data: { name: <anything>, sf: <something> }, method: "add" }
          console.log(data);

          $.ajax({
            url: '/temp',
            type: 'post',
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            processData: false
          }).done(data => {
            $('output[name="result"]').html(data);
          });
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Depending on the requirements, you can query the data on the server side using its key, since it has already been parsed from the JSON format.
Since you get a `dict` for your nested object because of this, a conversion to a string is necessary before you can write it to the file.

```
import json, os
from flask import (
    Flask, 
    render_template,
    request
)

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/temp', methods=['POST'])
def temp():
    data = request.json.get('data')
    method = request.json.get('method', 'add')
    if method == 'add' and data:
        path = os.path.join(app.static_folder, 'temp.txt')
        with open(path, 'a') as fp:
            print(json.dumps(data), file=fp)
    return app.send_static_file('temp.txt')
```

Please note that this is a simplified example trying to be based on your specifications.

Comment: Oh okey, so I basically need to convert the JSON to a string, then send as a string.

Comment: You convert a JavaScript object with [`stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) into a JSON formatted string. When this is sent to the server, the server parses it into a python [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). The set content type is a prerequisite for the server to interpret the message as JSON.